# Sorting the words in an array

Tags: java, sorting

Im working on a project to take all the words from a text document count how many times they appear, alphabetize them, and print them out.  I have done all of those steps but i still have a few problems with my output.
-I need to remove the duplicate words from the list so instead of printing:

```
Hello-3
Hello-2
Hello-1
Hi-2
Hi-1
```

like it does now it will just print:

```
Hello-3
Hi-2
```

-The second thing i have to do is remove all numbers and punctuation from the text:
**If the input was:**

```
This3 
test 
is 
a 
2nd! 
Test. 
Te 
st
```

Then we would count one occurrence of ‘`this`’, one occurrence of ‘`is`’, one occurrence of ‘`a`’, one occurrence of ‘`nd`’, 2 occurrences of ‘`test`’, one occurrence of ‘`te`’ and one occurrence of ‘`st`’.

Comment: You should search for "remove duplicate words from list (language)" and "remove punctuation from text (language)".

Comment: language? what do you have until now?

Comment: Ok thanks ill try searching that im using java

Comment: I tried going into the print-statement and running a method to check if each character in the array[i] was a letter and if so print it out if not print nothing out but couldnt get that to work

Comment: Im also using a regular array not arraylist if that affects anything

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash table to store the words as keys and the counts as values

Hash tables ( known as associative arrays or dict in other languages) only allow unique keys

This perl one liner demonstrates the concept

```
perl -n -e '$a{$_}++ for(split(/\s+/)); END { use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(\%a);}' corpus.txt
```

Here's the same kind of thing in python

```
counter = dict()
for line in open("corpus.txt").readlines():
    for word in line.split(" "):
        v = counter.get(word, 0)
        counter[word] = v + 1

for word in sorted(counter.keys()):
    print "%d \t %s" % (counter[word], word)
```

You've just edited your question to say it's in java.  In java, there are HashMap types
you can use, here's an example declaration

```
HashMap<String, Integer> lookup = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

As for the second part of your question, a regular expression might work - although removing some characters like you describe is actually quite complicated to do rigorously.

A regexp substitution like this

```
s/[^\w\s]//g
```

means

- s for substitute, s/1/2 means substitute a 1 for a 2
- [ start a character class
- ^ inside a character class match the opposite to the class
- \w alphabetic letters
- \s whitespace
- ] end of character class
- the g at the end is a "global" flag, apply repeatedly to the input

so match anything that is not a space or a letter and replace with nothing, ie remove it

To use in the perl one liner above

```
perl -n -e 's/[^\w\s]//g; $a{$_}++ for(split(/\s+/)); END { use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(\%a);}' corpus.txt
```

python, java and other languages have regular expression systems too